# Easy as $3.14$ question

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

I've got the following question with the hint "Easy as $3.14$".
$$2003 = 2\\1337 = 4\\7877 = 3\\5732 = 4\\8315 = 3\\4466 = 0\\0354 = 2\\8923 = 2\\8888 = 0\\0000 = 0\\4059 = 1\\2403 = \ ?$$

I need to solve the question mark.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Pi sounds like prime. What's the number of pi, sorry prime.

Comment: the answer is $2$

Comment: Where does this question come from ?

Comment: I saw this question at https://www.transip.nl/jointhepartytoday You can win a Raspberry Pi!

Comment: This question is from a competition where the prize is a Raspberry Pi. Safe to say it's kind of cheating to ask it here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very suspect question. One that someone may find many answers to. In this case I believe the desired solution is that for four digits $abcd$. Then $abcd =$ the number of primes out of $\{a,b,c,d\}$. Hence $2403 = 2$ is probably the intended answer.

Edit : 1 is also included as a prime here. Although in general it is not considered to be one.

Comment: The first entry is $2003=2$ therefore it's more likely prime digits (and letting 1 be prime as well).

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Totally different reasoning to my answer but exactly the same output because they coincide.

Answer (score 5):

This is a spin on an old problem - count the circles in a number f.e. $8888 = 8$, or $6655 = 2$. This explains why the question is titled "Easy as 3.14", it is referring to a closed loop. There is no mathematical formula for calculating it, you have to look typographically:

$1111 = 4,$ all 4 of the numbers don't have a loop in them.

$0000 = 0,$  all 4 of the numbers have a loop in them.

So, the answer by this logic would be:

$2403 = 2$, as $\{ 4,0\}$ have loops.

Answer (score 2):

I notice a pattern which ist$ 4-n$
Where $ n $ is how many digits are written by overlapping. 
Eg 1, 2, 3, 5 and 7 don't overlap
4, 6, 8, 9 and 0 overlap.

Assuming this the answer is 2.

My reasoning works for all the numbers you gave but might not be the desired solution.

Comment: Funnily enough, your overlapping numbers are the prime numbers including $1$. So your solution is the same as the one given by @harrydunlop.

Answer (score 2):

The first two equations imply that $2001=0$ and $1333=0$, but $2001$ and $1333$ are coprime, so we must be working modulo $1$. (And the rest of the equations are indeed true modulo $1$). Therefore the correct answer is that $2403 = \mathit{anything\;at\;all}$.